MySQL scaffold Error: The given key '3072' was not present in the dictionary. at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
I trying to run scaffold below EF Core for MySQL database:
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=example.com;port=3306;user=admin;password=xxxxxxxx;database=abc_db;CharSet=utf8" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o Models -f

but getting error:
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key '3072' was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.set_CharacterSetIndex(Int32 value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField[] columns)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId, Int32 numCols)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()

This is EFcore detail
enter image description here
MySQL version is: 8.0.35
admin_tls_version   TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
immediate_server_version    999999
innodb_version  8.0.35
original_server_version 999999
protocol_version    10
replica_type_conversions    
slave_type_conversions  
tls_version TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
version 8.0.35
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
version_compile_zlib    1.3

Could you please give me an advice ?
I hvae tried to change connection string with the Chatset to CharSet=utf8mb4 but it doesn't work

Use Pomelo provider instead of official driver.

I have resolved the issue by upgrading MySql.Data nuget package to version 8.0.30

Do not use MySql.Data in production. It is buggy provider and do not support async operations natively.

What should we use EF core for MySQL @SvyatoslavDanyliv ?

This one Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
